# How to display current user name in View from firebase?

Tags: java, android

I'm still a beginner I'm trying to get current username from Firebase.

I did this code but it shows nothing.

```
public class OrderDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView currentUserName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        currentUserName =  findViewById(R.id.fullname);

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {

            String name = user.getDisplayName();

            currentUserName.setText(name);
        }


    }
.....
```

Comment: Check if it enters the if statement, to check wheather you really get a not null element

Comment: What type of Sign-in-method do you using now?

Comment: The type of sign-in method is Email/Password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you use auth providers like **Gmail**, **Facebook** then basic
>   profile info is automatically saved by firebase. If you are using some
>   custom authentication method like **Email/Password** then you have to update the
>   profile info after **creation/logged in**.

If you set the `DisplayName` of the user during creation then you can fetch the display name using `getDisplayName()` method for logged in user. Check below:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if(user != null) {
    String displayName = user.getDisplayName();
}
```

If you don't set the user profile info during creation then first of all you have to set this, then you can use it. To update profile info check below:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if(user != null) {
    UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
            .setDisplayName("Developer").build();

    user.updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

For further informations [check official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#update_a_users_profile).

Comment: I'm using the email/password sign-in method. what is the reason that my code shows nothing on the view?

Comment: By default Firebase only set **Email** and ***Password**. You have to set displayName/ imageUrl manually. Did you set this before?

Comment: If not then use above code to set. Also read the answer carefully. Thanks

Comment: There's no option such as displayName in firebase authentication

Comment: Yes, no options to manually set it from firebase console. you have to set it programmatically from your code during `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` or later after logged in